# MYSQL select one column group by other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with data like below:

[image]

And I would like to have the below output:

[image]

Actually I would like to do something like:

```
select CustomerName, (select sum(Amount) from tbl where tbl.CustomerName = CustomerName) as Amount, consumedDate from tbl
```

But since the data is fetched using subquery, so I am unable to use subquery in the select statement to select the Amount:

```
select CustomerName, (select sum(Amount) from myTable where myTable.CustomerName = tbl.CustomerName) as Amount, consumedDate from (select CustomerName, Amount, ConsumedDate from myTable) as tbl
```

The above query will cause an error:

```
Table tbl doesn't exist
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using variables for this purpose.  This require two passes:

```
select customername, consumeddate,
       (@a := if(@c = customername, @a,
                 if(@a := customername, cume_amount, cume_amount)
                )
       ) amount
from (select t.*,
             (@a := if(@c = customername, @a + amount,
                       if(@c := customername, amount, amount)
                      )
             ) as cume_amount
      from (<your subquery here>) t cross join
           (select @c := '', @a := 0) params
      order by customername
     ) t cross join
     (@ac := '', @a := 0) params
order by customername, cume_amount desc;
```

The first pass calculates a cumulative sum for each customer.  The second copies the maximum value back to all the rows for the customer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.CustomerName, b.amt, a.consumedDate
FROM tbl a, (
    SELECT CustomerName, sum(Amount) amt
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY 1
) as b
WHERE a.CustomerName = b.CustomerName
```

And here is an SQL by good student:

```
SELECT a.CustomerName, b.Amount, a.consumedDate
FROM tbl AS a
JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerName, sum(Amount) Amount
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY CustomerName
) AS b ON a.CustomerName = b.CustomerName
```

Comment: Don't use this old style joins in where clause it is discouraged

Comment: The point of the OP is *not* to refer to the table twice because it is a complex subquery.  I can understand the answer, but not the upvotes (and that is even putting aside the bad join syntax).

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCampos and goron-linoff, I will use JOIN keywords from today on

Comment: Hi @JorgeCampos, is GROUP BY 1 also a bad habit ?

Comment: I would said that yes, but not because of any performance or the language itself, it is just because your statement became harder to read. Although it exists to facilitate some use of columns in SQL queries. There is lots of discussion about it. One would say that it turns it easier to reuse a field that is some kind of complex calculation like `select (((fieldA + fieldB)/100)*2 )^fieldC/fieldD, max(someOtherColum) from X group by (((fieldA + fieldB)/100)*2 )^fieldC/fieldD` so in that specific cases I would definetely use group by 1 ! Some RDBMs doesn't allow you to use aliesed columns

Comment: @JorgeCampos agree, GROUP BY 1 is handy when column is complex calculated. as a result i use 1 for normal fields as well for coding consistence :) Thank.